# Make a new image appear by clicking on the previous image

Tags: javascript

I want to write a code in which when you click on an image another image appears. After that when you click on the new image, *another* one appears, and so on.

I wrote this code which works for the first image. I can't figure out how to define the appeared images as inputs.

```js
var i = 1

function addimage() {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = "images/d" + i + ".jpg";
  document.body.appendChild(img);
}

function counter() {
  i = i + 1
}
```

```html
<input type="image" src="images/d1.jpg" onclick="addimage(); counter();">
```

Comment: you will need to assign click handler on all newly added images

Comment: and can you tell me how should i do that Ramanlfc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach an `onclick` function to the new image, with the same code as in your `input` tag:

```js
var i = 1

function imageClick() {
  if (! this.alreadyClicked)
  {
    addimage();
    counter();
    this.alreadyClicked = true;
  }
}

function addimage() {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = "http://placehold.it/" + (200 + i);
  img.onclick = imageClick;
  document.body.appendChild(img);
}

function counter() {
  i = i + 1
}
```

```html
<input type="image" src="http://placehold.it/200" onclick="imageClick();">
```

Answer (score 1):

To add an event handler to an element, there are three methods; only use one of them:

=> With an HTML attribute. I wouldn't recommend this method because it mixes JS with HTML and isn't practical in the long run.

```
<img id="firstImage" src="something.png" onclick="myListener(event);" />
```

=> With the element's attribute in JS. This only works if you have a single event to bind to that element, so I avoid using it.

```
var firstImage = document.getElementById('firstImage');
firstImage.onclick = myListener;
```

=> By binding it with JavaScript. This method has been standardized and works in all browsers since IE9, so there's no reason not to use it anymore.

```
var firstImage = document.getElementById('firstImage');
firstImage.addEventListener("click", myListener);
```

Off course, myListener needs to be a function, and it will receive the event as its first argument.

In your case, you probably don't want to add another image when you click on any image that isn't currently the last. So when a user clicks on the last image, you want to add a new image and stop listening for clicks on the current one.

```
var i = 1;

function addNextImage(e) {
   // remove the listener from the current image
   e.target.removeEventListener("click", addNextImage);

   // create a new image and bind the listener to it
   var img = document.createElement("img");
   img.src = "http://placehold.it/" + (200 + i);
   img.addEventListener("click", addNextImage);
   document.body.appendChild(img);

   // increment the counter variable
   i = i + 1;
}

var firstImage = document.getElementById("firstImage");
firstImage.addEventListener("click", addNextImage);
```

[Try on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lo1fu5h2/)

---

On a side note: while JavaScript does support omitting some semi-columns it's considered a better practice to put them, and it will avoid small mistakes.

Comment: Sorry for the quick edits, I posted without proof-reading. There, I'm done.

Comment: that is great paul. just the final question is that only the first picture transforms the mous on hoover. can we do it to others too? so that the user can understand that they are clickable.
thanks

Comment: thank you so much Jacque. i need sometime to read it and understand. :)